# Delegate in separate class Swift

Tags: swift, class, delegates

I want to make a delegate in separate class like:

```
class MapViewAnnotationDelegate: NSObject, SomeDelegate { //...}
```

and then in my controller I want to assign:

```
someView.delegate = MapViewAnnotationDelegate()
```

but the delegate is nil... how to achieve such effect? I read something about strong in Objective-C but as far as I happen to know the strong is default in Swift.

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you posted more of your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing is fine, but you need something to hold onto your instance. `delegate` properties by tradition are `weak`, so they don't ensure that the object is retained. Something else must retain it. The most common solution is to add a property to the class that owns `someView`, and assign your `MapViewAnnotationDelegate` to that property before assigning it as the delegate. That way it won't be deallocated as long as the containing objet lives. But anything that retains it is ok.

Your current code currently does this:

- Create MapViewAnnotationDelegate
- Assign it to someView.delegate
- Note that there are no strong references to MapViewAnnotationDelegate (since someView.delegate is a weak reference)
- Destroy MapViewAnnotationDelegate
- Set someView.delegate to nil

One way this may look would be like this:

```
class Owner {
    let mapViewAnnotationDelegate = MapViewAnnotationDelegate()

    let someView: ...

    init() {
        someView.delegate = mapViewAnnotationDelegate
    }
}
```

In this configuration, `Owner` (which is the owner of `someView`) holds onto the delegate for its lifetime.

Comment: Okay thanks a lot. Unfortunately I pretty new to iOS development. Could you maybe provide me with some code please?

Comment: Update: according to  https://krakendev.io/blog/weak-and-unowned-references-in-swift i should 'just' make 'let' and assign to it my delegate... after that I should assigne to something.delegate = thatLet... but still it doesn't work :(

Comment: I suspect you put the `let` assignment inside a function. When the function returns, that variable will be released, and the object will go away. You need the variable to exist for the lifetime of `someView`.

Comment: Yes, thats right. I will try it later but I see that I have to make a 'field' (variable in class) containing this delegate and then assign it. Thanks! :)